# Ember JS - Handlebars template - @index being undefined inside #each

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I looked for a duplicate question but couldn't find one on SO. Hence here it goes.

I have an `#each` block in my template which is successfully printing the values from an array but when I try to get the current index using `@index` within that block like this - `{{@index}}`, it's undefined.

From the [official handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) I found this way of getting the current index.

**The Router (router.js) :**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("books", function(){
        this.route("about", { path : "/:bookId"}, function(){

        });
    });
});
```

**The Route (routes/books.js) :**

```
var BooksRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [{
            name: "Harry Potter & The Deathly Hallows"
        }, {
            name: "What If?"
        }, {
            name: "Diary of a Wimpy Kid"
        }, {
            name: "The Martian"
        }];
    }
});

export default BooksRoute;
```

**The Template (templates/books/index.hbs) :**

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>All Books!</h1>
    <ul>
        {{#each book in model}}
            {{@index}}
            <li>{{#link-to "books.about"}} {{book.name}} {{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is to generate link to each book with the current index being used as the `:bookId` e.g. `/books/1`.

Is there anything wrong in my code? How can I make it work?

**UPDATE :** <s>I have tried `{{#each model  as |book index|}}` as well with no luck.</s>

It works with `{{#each model  as |book index|}}`. Problem was me doing `{{@index}}` instead of `{{index}}` with the new approach.

Comment: try using this {{#each model as |book index|}}{{index}}
            <li>{{#link-to "books.about"}} {{book.name}} {{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}

Comment: no luck. still `undefined`

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sidajasara/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes it does work in the demo but not in my project? ! :(

Comment: sorry. it does work. my bad. i was still trying to print `{{@index}}`. Thanks a lot. can you add that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Since ember 1.11.0 index support has been added to the each helper.](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_each-with-index) You can use it like

```
{{#each model as |book index|}}
  {{index}}
        <li>{{#link-to "books.about" index}} {{book.name}} {{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

[Here is a working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sidajasara/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: this also seems like a better approach than `@index` that index can now be passed to other things more naturally.